# Testing Password Length with RSpec Using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to test my User model (using the `devise` gem). I'm running on the `rails4` branch of the `devise` gem. And I'm trying to write a test for the minimum password length.

In my `user_spec.rb`, I've written:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before { @user = User.new(full_name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar") }

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:full_name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  # it { should ensure_length_of(:password).is_at_least(8) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe 'when full name is not present' do
    before { @user.full_name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe 'when email is not present' do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe 'when password is not present' do
    before {@user.password = " "}
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe 'when password is too short' do
    it { should ensure_length_of(:password).is_at_least(8) }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

However, I'm still getting this failure/error when running `rspec spec/`:

```
Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
expected #<User id: nil, email: "user@example.com", encrypted_password:
"$2a$04$/Ifwb1dmfzG6xtBS/amRfOrTTopd8P6JSV48L0G/SWSh...",
reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil,
remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil,
last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil,
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, full_name: "Example User"> to be valid,
but got errors: Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: `foobar` is 6 characters long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, your spec file is working just fine.

Your `it { should be_valid }` test is failing on Line 14. This is failing because you have password as "foobar" which is just 6 characters long, and thus makes the user invalid.

Try changing

```
before do  
  @user = User.new(
    full_name: "Example User", 
    email: "user@example.com", 
    password: "foobar", 
    password_confirmation: "foobar")
end
```

to:

```
before do  
  @user = User.new(
    full_name: "Example User", 
    email: "user@example.com", 
    password: "foobar123", 
    password_confirmation: "foobar123")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The User you created for your test has not a valid password. So your test is actually guaranteeing the intended behavior.

Change your Test User password to something like: "long test password" and it should work alright.

Best regards